# How to add a tiny system for factory test in Android?

Tags: android, recovery

In factory test, testing screen,touch,buttons and other peripherals,the fully loaded  android boot time is too long ,and an extra factory test image is needed.

I wondered if I could boot a tiny system of android in a factory test mode，attaching the least needed components to do a fast factory test.

And also, with the normal boots up mode together in one image.

I found recovery like system may be a good way for it .

Is anyone know how to add a recovery like tiny test system in android?

Or there is a better way for a tiny test mode in Android?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I use the miniui lib in recovery to build a tiny Linux application to do the test job without load android framework by add trigger in  init.rc

The code is simple but really do the job